# Angular 2 Pipe not found

Tags: angular, angular2-pipe

I followed this link to create my own time ago pipe:
[Angular 2 "time ago" pipe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36663148/angular-2-time-ago-pipe)

but when I injected and used it, I saw the error:

> Template parse errors: The pipe 'timeAgo' could not be found

Below is my code, please help me to resolve this issue, many thanks!!

timeAgo.pipe.ts

```
import { Pipe, ChangeDetectorRef } from '@angular/core';
import { AsyncPipe } from '@angular/common';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/add/observable/interval';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/startWith';

@Pipe({
    name: 'timeAgo',
    pure: false
})
export class TimeAgoPipe extends AsyncPipe {
    value: Date;
    timer: Observable<string>;

    constructor(private ref: ChangeDetectorRef){
        super(ref);
    }

    transform(obj: any, args?: any[]): any {
        if(obj instanceof Date) {
            this.value = obj;

            if(!this.timer) {
                this.timer = this.getObservable();
            }
            return this.timer;
        }
        return this.transform(obj, args);

    }

    private getObservable(){
      const INTERVAL = 1000 * 45;

      const ONE_MINUTE = 60;
      const ONE_HOUR = 60 * 60;
      const ONE_DAY = 60 * 60 * 24;
      const ONE_MONTH = 60 * 60 * 24 * 30;
      const ONE_YEAR = 60 * 60 * 24 * 30 * 12;

      return Observable.interval(INTERVAL).startWith(0).map(() => {
        // current time
        let now = Date.now();

        // time since message was sent in seconds
        let delta = (now - this.value.getTime()) / 1000;

        // format string
        if(delta < ONE_MINUTE) {
          return 'just now';        
        }
        if(delta < ONE_HOUR) {
          return Math.floor(delta / ONE_MINUTE) + 'min(s) ago';
        }
        if(delta < ONE_DAY) {
          return Math.floor(delta / ONE_HOUR) + 'hour(s) ago';
        }
        if(delta < ONE_MONTH) {
          return Math.floor(delta / ONE_DAY) + 'day(s) ago';
        }
        if(delta < ONE_YEAR) {
          return Math.floor(delta / ONE_MONTH) + 'month ago';
        }

      });
    }
}
```

main.ts

```
import { bootstrap }    from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';
import { enableProdMode, provide, PLATFORM_PIPES } from '@angular/core';
bootstrap(AppComponent, [
  APP_ROUTER_PROVIDERS,
  provide(PLATFORM_PIPES, {
    useValue: [TimeAgoPipe],
    multi: true
  })
]);
```

post.component.html

```
<ul *ngIf="posts">
  <li *ngFor="let post of posts">
    {{ post.created_at | timeAgo}}     
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Have you imported pipe in your post.component.ts something like this - import { TimeAgoPipe } from './timeAgo.pipe';

Comment: I use the pipe globally, so that i import it in main.ts

Comment: Sounds like https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/8694. I assume pipes extending other classes is still broken.

Comment: make sure to add pipe to your declarations in the main.ts

Answer (score 2):

This occurs because your `TimeAgoPipe` inherits from `AsyncPipe`. I don't know about the behavior during the Angular2 beta builds, but Angular 2.2.x consistently fails to find inherited `@Component`, `@Pipe` and `@Directive` classes during template compilation for me.

It seems there are some very good reasons Angular2 doesn't support component inheritance: https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/7968

If you're looking for a `TimeAgoPipe` compatible with Angular 2.2, have a look at my [answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40907647/125407) or have a direct look at the [gist](https://gist.github.com/JohannesRudolph/8e6de056d9e33353f940d9da9e6ffd82).

Answer (score 1):

It seems to be that `PLATFORM_PIPES` is being deprecated (https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md).

You can use the method provided in this article to set global pipe: https://medium.com/@jecelynyeen/angular2-platform-pipes-globally-available-custom-pipe-will-be-deprecated-soon-c6ad16812c11#.ntmim1t9x

```
bootstrap(AppComponent, [
  provide(CompilerConfig, {
    useValue: new CompilerConfig({
      platformPipes: [...COMMON_PIPES, TimeAgoPipe],
      platformDirectives: [...COMMON_DIRECTIVES],
      genDebugInfo: true
    })
  }),
]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Even though I added MomentModule as a global import, I put

```
import { MomentModule } from 'angular2-moment';
```

and put I MomentModule like so

```
...
imports: [
    ...,
    MomentModule,
    ...,
]
```

under the corresponding *.module.ts, in your case it would be post.component.module.ts

as advised in the link below

[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47182015/template-parse-the-pipe-could-not-be-found#*=*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47182015/template-parse-the-pipe-could-not-be-found#_=_)