# Template parse: The pipe could not be found

Tags: angular, ionic2, angular2-moment

I am getting the error:

> Template parse errors: The pipe 'amDateFormat' could not be found

Here is my `app.module.ts`

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
...
import { MomentModule } from 'angular2-moment';
...

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    MyApp
  ],
  imports: [
    ...
    MomentModule,
    ...
  ],
  bootstrap: [IonicApp],
  entryComponents: [
    MyApp
  ],
  providers: [
    ...
  ]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Then in `service-booking-details.ts` I am doing the following:

```
import { Component} from '@angular/core';
import { IonicPage, NavController, NavParams} from 'ionic-angular';
import { MomentModule } from 'angular2-moment';
...    

@IonicPage()
@Component({
  selector: 'page-item-detail',
  templateUrl: 'service-booking-detail.html'
})
export class ServiceBookingDetailPage {
  service: any;
  ...

  constructor(..., navParams: NavParams, ...) {
    this.service = navParams.get('service');
  }
}
```

Then in the `service-booking-detail.html` template I am trying to **use a pipe from angular2-moment**:

```
<ion-content>

    <ion-card>
      <ion-card-content>
         <p>{{ service.data | amDateFormat:'LL' }}</p>
      </ion-card-content>
    </ion-card>

</ion-content>
```

It then throws the error "*Template parse errors: The pipe 'amDateFormat' could not be found*".

How do I import the MomentModule so that I can use it in templates without getting errors?

Comment: Please create a reproduction of the  problem to debug. The template-content you have shown seems irrelevant since the pipe mentioned in the error is `amDateFormat` not `amTimeAgo`.

Comment: That was a copy/pasting error from when I was trying to debug and use other pipes from angular2-moment module. Example above is throwing the error when trying to use | amDateFormat:'LL' pipe also.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I was able to get this working by importing this into the specific pages *.module.ts file.

Answer (score 4):

If this exists in the spec file (Jasmine, protractor)

```
import { MomentModule } from "ngx-moment";

beforeEach(() => {
    
      imports: [ MomentModule ]
  });
```

**Worked for me**

Answer (score 3):

In my case moving the `MomentModule` import from `app.module.ts` to the same module as component was fixed it.

Answer (score 3):

You can add momentModule to *specific page module*, or it'd be better to add it on **shared module**.

Hope it helps you.