# Difference between two dates in Days using angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, date, angular8

In my application I am getting message sent date from  API response, I want to calculate the difference between current date and the date from API response in days(difference) using angular 8 and map in ngFor.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-xv1twv?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

Please help me. Should I use moment.

Comment: moment js really simplifies anything to do with time and date.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25150570/get-hours-difference-between-two-dates-in-moment-js

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Javascript library for human-friendly relative date formatting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7641791/javascript-library-for-human-friendly-relative-date-formatting)

Comment: moment would be an easy way to generate the friendly text https://momentjs.com/docs/#/durations/humanize/. Although I would wrap this functionality in to a filter.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Angular 2 "time ago" pipe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36663148/angular-2-time-ago-pipe)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3224834/get-difference-between-2-dates-in-javascript

Comment: Working demo using `moment` https://angular-etkvgv.stackblitz.io

Answer (score 27, accepted):

If this is all you need you can add plain code. For example:

```js
calculateDiff(dateSent){
    let currentDate = new Date();
    dateSent = new Date(dateSent);

    return Math.floor((Date.UTC(currentDate.getFullYear(), currentDate.getMonth(), currentDate.getDate()) - Date.UTC(dateSent.getFullYear(), dateSent.getMonth(), dateSent.getDate()) ) /(1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
}
```

You need to update your HTML to send the right date.

Example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-bf5qer?file=src/app/app.component.ts

The code is adapted from https://www.w3resource.com/javascript-exercises/javascript-date-exercise-8.php and may require a few tests.

Answer (score 10):

You don't need to use momentjs.

```js
  calculateDiff(data){
    let date = new Date(data.sent);
    let currentDate = new Date();

    let days = Math.floor((currentDate.getTime() - date.getTime()) / 1000 / 60 / 60 / 24);
    return days;
  }
```

```html
<div *ngFor="let data of responseData" class="dataHolder">
  <div>{{data.title}}</div>
  <div>{{data.type}}</div>
  <div>{{data.msg}}</div>
   Message sent on: <div>{{data.sent}}</div>
   <div style="font-weight:bold;">sent {{calculateDiff(data)}}_ days ago</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

Try like this:

**[Working Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-bsliue?embed=1&file=src/app/app.component.ts)**

.html

```
<div style="font-weight:bold;">sent {{calculateDiff(data.sent)}}_ days ago</div>
```

.ts

```
calculateDiff(sentDate) {
    var date1:any = new Date(sentDate);
    var date2:any = new Date();
    var diffDays:any = Math.floor((date2 - date1) / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));

    return diffDays;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

[Working demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-b9df7k)

```
  <div style="font-weight:bold;">sent {{calculateDiff(data.sent)}} days ago</div>
```

ts file:

```
 calculateDiff(sentOn){

            let todayDate = new Date();
            let sentOnDate = new Date(sentOn);
            sentOnDate.setDate(sentOnDate.getDate());
            let differenceInTime = todayDate.getTime() - sentOnDate.getTime();
            // To calculate the no. of days between two dates
            let differenceInDays = Math.floor(differenceInTime / (1000 * 3600 * 24)); 
            return differenceInDays;
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

In your html, pass the dateString to the c**alculateDiff** function

```
<div style="font-weight:bold;">sent {{calculateDiff(data.sent)}} days ago</div>
```

In your ts, change your code like this,

```
calculateDiff(date: string){
    let d2: Date = new Date();
    let d1 = Date.parse(date); //time in milliseconds
    var timeDiff = d2.getTime() - d1;
    var diff = timeDiff / (1000 * 3600 * 24);
    return Math.floor(diff);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please see [this](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-dog76y). You have to pass date `calculateDiff(data.sent)`