# Make pipe refresh it self in angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have static timestamp from backend and I want to refresh the pipe every 1 second to get date from now
and this my pipe

```
    import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';
import moment from 'moment';
@Pipe({
  name: 'dateFormat'
})
export class DateFormatPipe implements PipeTransform {

  transform(date: string): string {

    return moment.utc(date, 'X').local().format('DD-MM-YYYY h:mm:ss a');
  }

}
```

in this case it just convert time stamp to this format , I want to keep date updated how can I do this ?

Answer (score 6):

You should return an observable and use asyncPipe as well.

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';
import * as moment from 'moment';
import { interval, Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';
@Pipe({
  name: 'dateFormat'
})
export class DateFormatPipe implements PipeTransform {

  transform(date: string): Observable<string> {
    return interval(1000).pipe(map(() => { return moment().format('DD-MM-YYYY h:mm:ss a') }));
  }

}
```

And you should use it like:
`{{ 'param' | dateFormat | async}}`

Comment: Use `timer(0, 1000)` instead of `interval(1000)` if you want the pipe to return immediately! https://stackoverflow.com/a/44166071/2966288

Answer (score 0):

I think you just have to refresh your time that is passed into the pipe every second?

Like

```
currentTime$ = Observable.interval(1000).pipe(map(() => { return new Date() } ))
```

Comment: I have tried it but it doesn't work

Comment: You use it in html like (currentTime$ | async) | dateFormat

Comment: `return interval(1000).pipe(map(() => { return  moment.utc(date, 'X').local().format('DD-MM-YYYY h:mm:ss a')} ))
 `

Comment: **error**  Argument of type 'unknown[]' is not assignable to parameter of type 'OperatorFunction<number, any>'.
  Type 'unknown[]' provides no match for the signature '(source: Observable<number>): Observable<any>'